# responsive navigation bar multiple issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

the issue I am experiencing at the moment creating my first own website is that I would like my nav bar to be sitting on the right not the left and once my media query has been met I would like the burger icon to show the list items in a block level but I am having trouble moving the list items to the right and also keeping the list items inline once the media query has been met.

I would also like the navigation bar to sit on top of the background colour.

I have tried changing the display elements to block and inline-block also using float right and google around for other options

```
.toggle  {
    padding-left: 48.5%;
    width: 100%;
     font-size: 40px;
     color: red;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: none;

}
.nav {
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
 ul li a {
     position: relative;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: red;
 }


#containernav.color {
    position: fixed;
    background: grey;
    transition: 0.5s;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0.2;
}



CSS


.toggle  {
    padding-left: 48.5%;
    width: 100%;
     font-size: 40px;
     color: red;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: none;

}
.nav {
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
 ul li a {
     position: relative;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: red;
 }


#containernav.color {
    position: fixed;
    background: grey;
    transition: 0.5s;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0.2;
}


JS




/* Responsive menu-icon */

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.menu').click(function() {
$('ul').toggleClass('active');

})
})
/* Sticky nav bar feature */

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop()) {
      $('#containernav').addClass('color');
    }
    else 
    {
      $('#containernav').removeClass('color');
    }
  });
```

The navigation bar should be positioned to the right. on top of the background colour grey

then once the media query has been met it should collapse into the burger icon and once the burger icon has been clicked it should then display in a block

Comment: PLEASE SEE THE CODE PEN https://codepen.io/Buxey/pen/YoPjxX

Comment: can you please provide fiddle or your host URL.

Comment: You didn't provide your media queries

Comment: use bootstrap !

Answer (score 0):

**You should have to try this for more item on right**

**css**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 920px)
@media only screen and (max-width: 875px)
ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}
```